# Github graphQL OrderBy

Tags: github, graphql, github-graphql

I have a GraphQL query.
I cannot understand why it is not working.

```graphql
{
  repositoryOwner(login: "Naramsim") {
    login
    repositories(first: 3, isFork: true, orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT}) {
      edges {
        node {
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Link](https://graphql-explorer.githubapp.com/?variables=%7B%7D&query=%7B%0A%20%20repositoryOwner(login%3A%20%22Naramsim%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20login%0A%20%20%20%20repositories(first%3A%203%2C%20isFork%3A%20true%2C%20orderBy%3A%20%7Bfield%3A%20CREATED_AT%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20description%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You've got an error

```
Argument 'orderBy' on Field 'repositories' has an invalid value.
Expected type 'RepositoryOrder'.
```

You forget to specify direction which is marked as mandatory. This will work:

```graphql
{
  repositoryOwner(login: "Naramsim") {
    login
    repositories(first: 3, isFork: true,  orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: ASC}) {
      edges {
        node {
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can I get all repositories without pagination?

Comment: @DaviWesley I think that's best asked in a separate question, if it hasn't been asked already (which it probably has)

Comment: Hi Alex, What about if I want to change the created_at field with dropdown? Like name etc. I need something dynamically.

Comment: @UfukUYSAL this is bit of work. You start with [dynamic react graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66811179/1705829) and then move on to the gui with react. As your comment is one year old, maybe you did that?

Comment: In the ordering, you use `CREATED_AT` with `_`. There is also [`CREATEDAT`](https://gist.github.com/MichaelCurrin/72dea64bad7e285323865788aa5871f6#file-owned_repos-gql) without hiven. What is the diff?

Comment: Can you point us to the docs where you got the snippet "Argument..." from? I [found](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#repository) repo object info, but without `orderby`.