# How to use dynamic graphql (string) from separate page in component React / React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo

I have a react-native functional component that uses Apollo useQuery hook to make some graphql queries. When this component is rendered, it receives an id prop from previous page. So I need to use this id in graphql query dynamically.

I can do it inside of the component easily like this

```
const query = gql`
  query MyQuery {
    getItems(id: \"${id}\") {
      items {
          name
          price
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(query);
```

But I need to put all my graphql queries into separate folders. I couldn't figure out how to send a prop to another page and just receive back the graphql string to use in useQuery hook.

So instead of putting const query to current page where I use 'useQuery', I need to receive it from another page.

I want to do something like this:

```
import Query from '../queries/itemQuery'

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(Query(id));
```

I tried this and similar things:

itemQuery.js

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
const itemQuery = (id) => { 
    gql`
      query MyQuery {
        getItems(id: ${id}) {
          items {
              name
              price
            }
          }
        }
      `;
export default itemQuery
```

And in main page where I use 'useQuery':

```
import Query from '../queries/itemQuery'
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(Query(id));
```

When I try to send id from main page to itemQuery.js it doesn't work. I'm getting different errors such as itemQuery is not a function etc. I also tried to make it as a function which returns query but it didn't work. I revised this question. Previous answers was not useful for me, I guess I explained it wrong. This is the first question I'm asking on stackoverflow so you can help me improve, just ask missing parts that I should've explained.

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#example-2

Comment: your idea is abusing graphql, answer is correct...search for  importing graphql files tutorials/articles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [variables](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#options) in your query. So pass `id` as variable in your query and then you can pass `id` variable value from anywhere in query.

So, first declare your query in `itemQuery.js` as following :

```
export const GET_ITEMS = gql`
  query getItems($id: String) {
    getItems(id: $id) {
      items {
          name
          price
        }
      }
    }
`;
```

Now, import query in your component as pass pass variable as below :

```
import { GET_ITEMS } from '../queries/itemQueries';

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(Query, {
  variables: {id: 'your_id`}
});
```

Note that I have used `$id: String` assuming that your `id` will be string. But you can use any type as your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I can already use it like this in main page. I guess I explained my question wrong.  I need to import this query from another page inside useQuery and also send id to that query inside it. So if I'm sending variable like you showed, How am i going to receive it on itemQuery.js file where I have the query string. Also how to export it? Thanks

Comment: @Canol **this is the right method**, no sending, no string literal manipulations ... query can/should be graphql only file (using some [webpack] graphql loader), w/o js, export needed ... just use this that way !

Comment: @Canol I updated the answer. You can create query in any .js file and import it. You don't need to worry about how to get variable in query. It will be automatically passed to the query.

Comment: Also you should rename `itemQueries.js` to `index.js` and then declare all the queries in that file like `export const GET_ITEMS = gql``; export const GET_COLLECTIONS = gql``; etc.